# pass non-static member function with neither virtual inheritance nor templates

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, virtual-inheritance

How do I pass the non-static member function `eval` of object `Problem1 obj` to the object `Solver solver` ?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<functional>

// non-templated class
struct Solver{
    std::function<void(double&, double&)>* f;
    double solve(){
        double y,x=1;
        for(long int i=0;i<10000;++i){
            (*f)(y,x); (*f)(x,y);
        }
        return y;
    }
};

// non-static class; unknown at implementation time of Solver
struct Problem1{
    double p;
    void eval(double& y, double& x){
        y = x*x - p;
    }
};

int main(){
    Problem1    obj;
    Solver      solver;
    solver.f = &(obj.eval); // pass non-static member function
    solver.solve();
}
```

Since one solver shall be used to solve very many different instances of various problem classes, I do not want to use templates. Since the solution of one problem object may require very many calls of `eval`, I am shy to use virtual inheritance from a `VirtualProblem` class due to the overhead and slow reputation of virtual classes in c++. Does this matter here? What should I do?

Comment: Unrelated: You can create an empty `std::function` object using [constructor signature `(1)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function), so there's usually no need to use a pointer to an `std::function` object.

Comment: `std::function` will also have overhead. `virtual`'s overhead isn't that big, typically it adds a couple levels of indirection when you call the function. A `vtable` implementation needs to follow a pointer to a table, then lookup a function pointer in that table. I'm not sure what the overhead on `std::function` is, but it is likely in the same order of magnitude. Since you are trying to save a pointer to a function and call a function  through it, you already have a level of indirection from the start.

Comment: Side note: `double solve(const std::function<void(double,double)> f) { ... }` might be a little better (with `solver.solve(obj.eval);`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `std::function` works.

First of all it should not be a pointer. You can't assign a pointer to a non-static member function to it (and especially not its pointer). And you can't use non-static member function that way.

To solve your problem first lets make `f` a non-pointer object:

```
struct Solver{
    std::function<void(double&, double&)> f;
    double solve(){
        double y,x=1;
        for(long int i=0;i<10000;++i){
            f(y,x); f(x,y);
        }
        return y;
    }
};
```

Then we can use a [*lambda*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to call the correct function on the correct object:

```
solver.f = [&obj](double& a, double& b)
{
    obj.eval(a, b);
};
```

---

On another note, if you want to return a value from a function, actually `return` a value. Please don't abuse reference arguments when it's not really needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help! On the return value comment: I did so because it is a minimum example. Probably, when passing nD arrays, you would agree it is better by reference/pointer.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed: your proposed code with the bind produces the following compiler error in GNU g++ 12.0.1: mini_main.cpp:27:92: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::function<void(double&, double&)>' and 'std::_Bind_helper<false, Problem1&, void (Problem1::*)(double&, double&), const std::_Placeholder<1>&, const std::_Placeholder<2>&>::type')
@Some-programmer-dude Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @DarikaRanganathan Hmm, that's odd, I thought I tested it and it did work, but not it doesn't. Maybe I'm hallucinating... :-) Anyway, I removed that option from the answer.

Comment: @DarikaRanganathan Regarding the return issue, if your requirement is to modify the first argument (value, array, etc.) in-place then pass it by reference, and for simple values pass the second argument by value, else pass it by constant reference. If there's no in-place requirement, then even for arrays and objects, I would still recommend returning a n actual value (or object). You could still return a value/object, and assign back to the variable you use for the first argument. The compiler can create pretty good optimized code for you, so don't think too much about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could use 'std::bind'